# Unable to install Docker DTR

Tags: docker, docker-ucp

I am trying to install docker DTR using a command mentioned below but getting failed

**Command:**

```
docker run -it --rm docker/dtr install \

  --ucp-node mbk-srv-389-ub \

  --ucp-username admin \

  --ucp-url https://172.16.217.1 \

  --ucp-insecure-tls
```

But its giving error

**ERROR:**

```
FATA[0006] Failed to choose ucp node: The UCP node 'mbk-srv-389-ub' has port conflicts, please pick another node or choose a different port.
```

So i tried to add port `445 **--ucp-url https://172.16.217.1:445**` as port 443 is also used by UCP but then it is showing another error.

**ERROR:**

```
FATA[0006] Failed to get new conv client: failed to create http client: Failed to get UCP CA: Get https://172.16.217.1:445/ca: dial tcp 172.16.217.1:445: connect: connection refused
```

**INFO:**
port `445` is open on the firewall.
 no other service is running on port 445

Answer (score 0):

DTR needs port 443 free, if 443 isn't free the install will fail.

Install UCP with `--controller-port` to any port other than 443 and then install DTR, it will work